# What's the tune that Noel is humming in Sora no Method?

Tags: music, sora-no-method

What's the tune that Noel is humming as heard in around 02:55 of Episode 5? It seems that Nonoka also knows that tune. It also played as the ED of Episode 7. Does someone know how to tranlate the credits? I think the title is stated somewhere there.

Comment: She hums it in [episode 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPAFygL5XsM), too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. The title of the OST is **Hoshi no kakera**. Hoshi no kakera is 2nd ending theme by fhana. It is the ending theme of Episode 7.

Comment: fhana - Hoshi no Kakera will release on Christmas Eve, 24 December 2014 link : http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2014/11/21-1/fhna-to-release-celestial-method-image-album-on-christmas-eve

Answer (score 1):

Nonoka was humming it as a child, it was her mother's song. Nonoka promised Noel to bring her mother to sing it for her but then moved away after returning home.

Comment: the bgm also played when they were lighting the sparklers